# How to mix colors in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

```css
.reviewed {
  background-color: rgba(228, 225, 219, 1);
}
.deleted {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>№</td>
    <td>Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="reviewed">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Ivan</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Andrey</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How can I make it so that when both the classes `.deleted` and `.reviewed` are set on an element the `background-color` of `.deleted` takes into account the `background-color` of `.reviewed`?

When using the two classes the color should be darker than if it was just using the class `.deleted`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a CSS preprocessor e.g. SASS/LESS you can simply define two color variables and use color mixing functions to generate the third color.

[SASS example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/akggar?editors=1100):

```css
$color1: rgba(228, 225, 219, 1);
$color2: red;

.reviewed {
  background-color: $color1;
}
.deleted {
  background-color: $color2;
}
.reviewed.deleted {
  background-color: mix($color1, $color2);
}
```

[LESS Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JKQQZQ?editors=1100)

Answer (score 10):

## `background-blend-mode` can allow you to blend two backgrounds together

In this instance `background-blend-mode: mulitply;` can give you the desired effect of darkening the `background-color` of `.deleted`.

The following changes are required:

- Change `background-color:rgba(228, 225, 219, 1);` to `background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(228, 225, 219, 1), rgba(228, 225, 219, 1));` in `.reviewed`. This will give `.reviewed` the same background colour but will enable `background-blend-mode` to work with the `background-color` set on `.deleted`
- Add `background-blend-mode: multiply;` to `.deleted` to enable the background colour to blend with the "background image" set on `.reviewed`

```css
.reviewed {
  background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(228, 225, 219, 1), rgba(228, 225, 219, 1));
}
.deleted {
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Number</td>
    <td>Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="reviewed">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Reviewed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="reviewed deleted">
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Reviewed and deleted</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="deleted">
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Deleted</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The advantage to this is that you don't have to specify a third colour as the calculation is done by CSS. The disadvantage is the there is currently no support for this in IE or Edge.

`background-blend-mode` is supported by Firefox, Chrome and partially supported by Safari. http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-backgroundblendmode

Answer (score 5):

```
.reviewed {
    background-color:rgba(228, 225, 219, 1);
}

.deleted {
    background-color:red;
}
.reviewed.deleted {
    background-color:/*use color code for something dark red*/
}
```

`.reviewed.deleted` means the element having class `reviewed`and`deleted`

Comment: Do it in this way

Answer (score 2):

you can set the css background to a gradient and produce a similiar effect as in photoshop

example gradient

```
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom right, red, rgba(255,0,0,0));
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(to bottom right, red, rgba(255,0,0,0));
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(to bottom right, red, rgba(255,0,0,0));
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(to bottom right, red, rgba(255,0,0,0));
```